# Terminating a nested context after the first output

Tags: esper

I have a game where I'm trying to implement a happy hour feature where if you earn a certain amount of points, during a certain time period each day you'll earn something. The event should only fire once in the hour as soon as the player meets the points requirement.

I've tried a couple different solutions:

```
create context HappyHourContext
    context InitCtx start (0, 16, *, *, *) end pattern[timer:at(0, 17, *, *, *) or TerminationEvent],
    context PartitionCtx partition by playerId from EarnPointsEvent, playerId from TerminationEvent;
 context HappyHourContext
     insert into TerminationEvent select playerId from EarnPointsEvent having sum(points) >= 100;
```

This only works for the first player due to the TerminationEvent not taking into account the partition.

The following query seem to work correctly however it seems pretty inefficient as it keeps processing events even after the event has been output.

```
create context HappyHourContext
    context InitCtx start (0, 16, *, *, *) end (0, 17, *, *, *),
    context PartitionCtx partition by playerId from EarnPointsEvent);

 context HappyHourContext
     select playerId from EarnPointsEvent having sum(points) >= 100 output first every 1 hours
```

Is there a way to terminate the context after the first event is output? or a better way to do this?

Edit:

I've also tried

```
create context HappyHourContext
    context InitCtx start (0, 16, *, *, *) end (0, 17, *, *, *),
    context PartitionCtx partition by playerId from EarnPointsEvent, playerId from TerminationEvent terminated by TerminationEvent;

 context HappyHourContext
     insert into TerminationEvent select playerId from EarnPointsEvent having sum(points) >= 100;
```

Unfortunately this outputs multiple events per player due to the InitCtx not being terminated when the PartitionCtx is.

Answer (score 0):

The "partition by" also accepts a "terminated by". [doc](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.3.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#context_def_keyed)

For single-row output use aggregation functions and/or group-by clause, i.e. "group by playerId" or "last(playerId)". By selecting a field of the event the output is row-per-event and not row-per-group. [doc](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.3.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_aggregation)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated my question with what I've tried for your suggestion. Unfortunately this outputs multiple events per player due to the InitCtx not being terminated when the PartitionCtx is.